# Date Conversion In java Web Application

Tags: java, date, web-applications, web, timezone

```
    String date1 = "13/03/2014 16:56:46 AEDT";

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss z");
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+12"));
    java.util.Date convertedDate = (java.util.Date) sdf.parse(date1);
    SimpleDateFormat outFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss z");
    outFormatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+12"));
    String output = outFormatter.format(convertedDate);
    System.out.println("Date in NZ Timezone : " + output);
```

I am trying to convert AEDT date into dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss z but it gives me exception :

Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "13/03/2014 16:56:46 AEDT"
 at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:337)

Please help me with this....

I need to convert users time in to my UTC time for making it same through my web-application  ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that Java does not support AEDT abbreviation, but since you know timezone offset you can doit this way

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+12"));
java.util.Date convertedDate = (java.util.Date) sdf.parse(date1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to be right, but AEDT is not a valid General Time Zone. Thats the reason for the `java.text.ParseException`. Instead you can do:

```
String date1 = "13/03/2014 16:56:46 "+TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-11").getID();
```

Input:

`13/03/2014 16:56:46 GMT+12:00`

Output:

`Date in NZ Timezone : Fr Mrz 14 2014 15:56:46 GMT+12:00`

It seems to work right:)

**From the Doc's:**

> **Three-letter time zone IDs**
>
> For compatibility with JDK 1.1.x, some
> other three-letter time zone IDs (such as "PST", "CTT", "AST") are
> also supported. However, their use is deprecated because the same
> abbreviation is often used for multiple time zones (for example, "CST"
> could be U.S. "Central Standard Time" and "China Standard Time"), and
> the Java platform can then only recognize one of them.